# Error: Filesystem is read only

Tags: debian, hard-drive

I've been having trouble with a debian system's file system going into read-only mode.  The short solution was to turn it off and back on again, but it keeps switching over to read only mode.  The debian machine is a VM on an ESXi hypervisor, and the volume is exported in /etc/exports so that other VMs can mount its subfolders in their own `/etc/fstab` configurations.

Client `/etc/fstab` configs:

```
# Remember NFS isn't secured over the network.. it probably wouldn't matter but is still considered non-secure
storage-host-vm:/storage/drv_a/workpro_backups_samba  /mnt/workpro_backups_samba  nfs      rw,sync,hard,intr  0     0
storage-host-vm:/storage/drv_b/temporary     /mnt/temporary               nfs      rw,sync,hard,intr  0     0
storage-host-vm:/storage/drv_a/staff_pc_file_backups  /mnt/staff_pc_file_backups        nfs      rw,sync,hard,intr  0     0
```

I just ran `fsck` and it gave the below output

```
$ sudo fsck /storage/drv_a
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
/dev/sdd1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sdd1: 264980/134217728 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 18092864/536870655 blocks
```

So did I just fix the fluke problem?  Or should I be shopping out a new hdd and deciding a data migration strategy since the drive is dieing?  Or is the fact that I'm exporting

The hard drive is "on" a 2TB 5400RPM Green Western Digital.  I think it must have worked fine originally when it was first integrated into the system...  It's purpose was for storing clonezilla HDD images (I DON'T make those often for obvious reasons ;) and holds a bunch of ISOs.  It also has a git repo that is committed to nightly for a legacy machine's backup purposes.  The drive wasn't by any means 'high end', but I'm still a bit frustrated because I've only used about 2% of this drive's capacity so far and would expect slightly better performance.  Is there a way I can "shut down" all the sectors that I've written to so far since I've apparently used them up?  Or what kind of a failure is this?  Its in a very well vented chasis with limited vibration and interferance.

Here's some highlights from `/var/log/messages`

```
[105762.692329] EXT4-fs warning (device sdd1): ext4_clear_journal_err:4365: Filesystem error recorded from previous mount: IO failure
[105762.692334] EXT4-fs warning (device sdd1): ext4_clear_journal_err:4366: Marking fs in need of filesystem check.
[105762.695164] EXT4-fs (sdd1): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
[105762.793436] EXT4-fs (sdd1): recovery complete

[119886.884295] sd 0:0:3:0: [sdd] Unhandled error code
[119886.884299] sd 0:0:3:0: [sdd]  Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[119886.884304] sd 0:0:3:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 72 8c 40 e0 00 00 90 00
[119886.884340] sd 0:0:3:0: [sdd] Unhandled sense code
[119886.884342] sd 0:0:3:0: [sdd]  Result: hostbyte=invalid driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[119886.884345] sd 0:0:3:0: [sdd]  Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[119886.884349] sd 0:0:3:0: [sdd]  Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[119886.884354] sd 0:0:3:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 72 8c 3f e0 00 01 00 00
[119890.019089] sd 0:0:3:0: [sdd] Unhandled sense code
[119890.019096] sd 0:0:3:0: [sdd]  Result: hostbyte=invalid driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[119890.019102] sd 0:0:3:0: [sdd]  Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[119890.019108] sd 0:0:3:0: [sdd]  Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard drive is having errors as suggested in another answer, get it replaced.

If you need the data it may be worthwhile to attempt a backup. Take the disk out and attached it to a different system. Then use (a variation of) dd to make a copy.

You could use ***ddrescue***:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

To find other useful guides on how to use it just do a quick https://www.duckduckgo.com search.

Alternatively the following ***dd*** command did help me out a couple of times when dealing with a bad disk. You can either use it only on those partitions you want to save, or the whole disk:

```
dd conv=noerror if=/dev/bad_disk of=/path/to/diskimage.img bs=500M
```

Use ***conv=noerror*** to avoid it stopping on errors, the amount of memory to add to the ***bs=*** argument should be about 1/4 to 1/2 of the RAM. In order to speed things up. The default is too low and causes ***dd*** to slow down a lot because it does too many disk operations. You may need to perform a filesystem check on the recovered image(s). If the file ***diskimage.img*** contains one partition you can mount it using:

```
 mount -o loop diskimage.img /mnt/point
```

Comment: Thanks for the input!  What happens if I try to copy over the files to another drive while they're mounted in this read only state?  This is happening on my primary storage server, so there's plenty of other HDDs to hop to in the meantime.

Comment: Copying files in a read only state is fine. However the disk errors may cause excessive interrupts which may slow down the rest of the system. If that happens it's probably best to remove it and do the recovery in a different system, unless of course the slow downs are not a problem.